# Asymptotical behavior of this sequence limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

A sequence is defined as $f(n)=\sum_{i=0}^nC_n^i\cdot i^{n-i}$, where $C_n^i$ is the combination number choosing $i$ from $n$. I would like to know how does the limit of this sequence behave like. According to numerical computation, it is potentially exponential.

Comment: It is obviously faster than exponential. For asymptotics, the e.g.f. is $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f(n)}{n!}x^n = e^{xe^x}$ (to start).

Comment: It will grow super-exponentially. The $i=n/2$ term grows like $\binom{n}{n/2} (n/2)^{n/2}\approx (2n)^{n/2}$. A good method would be to find the index $i(n)$ for which $a_i=\binom{n}ii^{n-i}$ is maximized. Then you get the estimate $a_{i(n)}\le (n)\le na_{i(n)}$, which is a great answer since the $n$ on the upper bound is small compared to $a_{i(n)}$.

Comment: This is [A000248](https://oeis.org/A000248) in the OEIS and it's the exponential generating function for $\exp\big(x\,\exp(x)\big)$.

It also counts the number of ways to partition $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ and elect a representative for each part.
To see this, in

$$f(n) =  \sum_{i=0}^n\,\binom ni i^{n-i}$$

we proceed as follows: first, we determine the number $i$ of classes in our partition.
Next, we elect $i$ representatives, one for each class, from among the $n$ possiblities in $\binom ni$ ways.
Finally, we assign each of the remaining $n-i$ elements to one of the $i$ classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [$\text{A000248}$](https://oeis.org/A000248) there are asymptotics (Harris and Schoenfeld, 1968) given by

$$f(n) \sim \sqrt{\frac{r+1}{2\pi(n+1)(r^2+3r+1)}}\,\exp\left(\frac{n+1}{r+1}\right)\,\frac{n!}{r^n},$$

where $r$ is the root of $r(r+1)\exp(r) = n+1$.